# Installing Net Framework 4 Remotely as an Administrator

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-4.0, puppet

I am trying to install the .net framework 4.0 remotely using the following commands

## 1

```
command => 'Powershell.exe -Verb RunAs -FilePath C:\Temp\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe -ArgumentList "/q /norestart /log C:\Temp\NetFx40.htm"'
```

## 2

```
command => 'C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe /c C:\Temp\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe /q /norestart /log C:\Temp\NetFx40.htm',
```

With both i get the following in the logs.  Btw the user running the command is a member of the Local Administrators Group.

```
Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x00000005), "Access is denied. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:00:55).
    OS Version = 6.1.7601, Platform 2, Service Pack 1
    OS Description = Win2K8R2 - x64 Standard Edition Service Pack 1
    CommandLine = D:\ecfcf956d61e2bf89c1c75ce16\\Setup.exe /q /norestart /log C:\Temp\NetFx40.htm /x86 /x64 /ia64 /web
    TimeZone = Eastern Standard Time
    Initial LCID = 1033
    Using Simultaneous Download and Install mechanism
    Operation: Installing
    Package Name = Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup
    Package Version = 4.0.30319
    User Experience Data Collection Policy: Disabled
    Number of applicable items: 11
    Exe (D:\ecfcf956d61e2bf89c1c75ce16\SetupUtility.exe) succeeded.
    Exe Log File: dd_SetupUtility.txt
    ServiceControl operation succeeded!
    ServiceControl operation succeeded!
    Exe (C:\Users\_BUILD~1\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Setup_4.0.30319\Windows6.1-KB958488-v6001-x64.msu) failed with 0x5 - Access is denied. .
    Final Result: Installation failed with error code: (0x00000005), "Access is denied. " (Elapsed time: 0 00:00:21).
```

Comment: Is UAC enabled? Sounds like it is. Local admin membership only allows you to get the UAC popoup. You still have to click yes in the popup to get access to install(admin rights). Do you have the possibility to disable UAC at these computers?

Comment: Thea UAC is disabled by default on all the domain servers. Also firewall is disabled by default on the domain

Comment: does it work if you run it using Invoke-Command in powershell ? `Invoke-Command -Scriptblock { C:\Temp\dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe /q /norestart /log C:\Temp\NetFx40.htm }`

Comment: It runs but not as administrator so i get the same error. This command will be executed from a puppet recipe to start provisioning a win2008r2 instance. The account trying to install the net framework remotely has local administration rights on the target machine.

Comment: Have you been able to solve this issue? I'm experiencing the same error while trying to provision a Window 7 system.

Comment: It seems that when you try to use winrm or powershell as a remote command it fails. However, If you execute the same command using let's say a local windows service or a windows task then it just works fine. 

https://github.com/WinRb/vagrant-windows/issues/166

Comment: You are getting this error because of installation of updates i.e .msu files. You can try SkipMSUInstall in your argument list which skips the installation of those updates.  
for e.g dotNetFx40_Full_setup.exe /q /norestart /SkipMSUInstall

Answer (score 1):

It won't work and [you're not the only one](http://www.indigoblue.co.uk/blog/devops-windows-fun-times-installing-net-4-over-winrm-winrs-windows-server-2008r2) bitten by this!

Read this Microsoft support article for a complete description:

[Windows Update Standalone Installer (WUSA) returns 0x5 ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED when deploying .msu files through WinRM and Windows Remote Shell](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2773898)

The workaround is to run the installer out-of-band from the WinRM/WinRS session.

Answer (score 0):

While installation of .NET framework 4.0, It installs some updates as well (.msu) files.

But when we are installaing .NET 4.0 remotely, It fails because of these updates. The reason behind that is, it's not allowable to install these updates remotely. Please find the KB article [enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/2773898). This article also mentioned the workaround for this.

We can skip this updates & we can only installs .NET framework 4.0 using following arguments :

```
dotnetfx40_Full_x86_x64.exe /norestart /SkipMSUInstall
```

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using [PSEXEC](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896649) from SysInternals.

`psexec.exe \\SERVERNAME /s \\networkshare\setup\ndp48-x86-x64-allos-enu.exe /passive /norestart /SkipMSUInstall`

Answer (score -1):

I was getting this same error as I attempted to remotely install .Net 4.0. To resolve it I used the below command, per [How can I remotely, programmatically install .NET 4 client on an Azure VM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20197954/how-can-i-remotely-programmatically-install-net-4-client-on-an-azure-vm) :

```
Invoke-Command -session $CompSession -scriptBlock {
Start-Process -FilePath "C:\dotnetfx40_Full_x86_x64.exe" `
-ArgumentList " /passive /norestart /SkipMSUInstall /log "C:\results.log" -PassThru | Wait-Process}
```